# what does " layers of clothing" mean?

Tags: word-usage

what does " layers of clothing" mean in the text below?

> Make sure you have everything you need for test day laid out in advance so you avoid last-­minute stress-this includes your ID, a snack, your test ticket, and **layers of clothing** in case the test room temperature is hot or cold.

Answer (score 2):

"Layers of clothing" means instead of one heavy woolen sweater, you should wear a few separate, thinner layers of clothing, like a thin shirt, with a light sweater over it, and maybe a warm vest or jacket on top of that. So if it's freezing cold in the test room, you can keep all the layers on. But if the room is too warm, you can remove a layer or two, and still be comfortable.